# Delphi: navigate2 with pdf files

Tags: delphi

I'm using Delphi 10.4.2 and I want to use the navigate2 method to open a pdf file in a browser.
This is the simple code:

```
br.HandleNeeded;
br.Stop;
br.Navigate2(URL);
```

where URL is the file path.

I noticed that navigate2 works and displays some files (.text, .html...) but not the .pdf files.

Has anyone ever had a similar problem? How can I fix? And, above all, why does it occur?

I have the Acrobat Reader additional component in the browser.

Comment: This is way too broad, including not even giving an example of your URL. Are you sure the browser in your program also has the plugins? Like Acrobat Reader? Did you even try to assure that?

Comment: The url is a parameter that comes from another function, and anyway I replaced it with a path to a generic file on my computer and it doesn't open. What do you mean by assure to have plugins? I see them in add-ons.

Comment: "_I see them in add-ons._" And you're talking about the browser in your program? Not the browser itself as its own program?

Comment: ok, then probably the error is as you say. How can I check?

Answer (score 0):

it seems a problem related to Acrobat Reader. It works with an other PDF reader.